# How do you detect a player's death?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can you use the `/testfor` command in Minecraft to detect if a player has died?

I need it for my map, where two players are pitted against each other. I want it so that when one of them dies, it will detect the death and declare the victor.

Answer (score 14):

The usual way to test for dead players is to set up a [scoreboard objective](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard). Check out the linked wiki page for general information, as well as the command reference for using scoreboards.

First, you have to set up an objective, I'll call it `hasDied` using

```
/scoreboard objectives add hasDied deathCount
```

Using the `deathCount` criterion means that it is automatically updated when someone dies. Now you can check whether a player has died using

```
/testfor @a[score_hasDied_min=1]
```

On a clock. The output of this command block will turn on once at least one player, somewhere, has a death score of at least 1. As part of this output (or the game start routine) you should reset the scoreboard objective for everyone using

```
/scoreboard players set @a hasDied 0
```

---

For an unknown number of players detecting the last man standing can be tricky, but it's doable. You can easily track people that have not died (using `@a[score_hasDied=0]`), and detect when the comparator outputs at signal strength 1.

Comment: 1.13 syntax for second command: `/execute if entity @a[scores={hasDied=1..}]`

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in a command block on a clock (if you wanna know a super fast clock just ask me) and put this command inside:

`/testfor (player name here or @a(all players) @p (nearest player) @e(nearest entity) (also you can add this to the end of @r or @e:[type=(entity name here (see all by typing /summon then pressing Tab))]`

then have a comparator coming off of that going into a block with a torch on it the connected to the torch would be your output.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute if entity ...`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a scoreboard. In this case, we have to add the scoreboard `deathCount` . You can name it whatever you like--for this example i'll name it `deaths`. Here's the command to add the scoreboard: `/scoreboard objectives add deaths deathCount`, then, in a separate command block, put: `/scoreboard players set @a deaths 0`. To testfor player's death, put in another command block: `/testfor @a[score_deaths_min=<number of deaths>]`. And there you go!

P.S. what is the name of your map, i'm gonna try to play it with my friend?

Comment: 1.13 syntax for last command: `/execute if entity @a[scores={deaths=<number_of_deaths..>}]`