# How can I check if an entire team has died?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a Minecraft minigame map using commandblocks (no code or mods). One of the game end conditions is that a team is eliminated.

How to I reliably check that a team has no members left alive on it?

I am using 1.8, and this will (obviously) be multiplayer

Comment: You're not using any building blocks? And what does the title means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set up an objective tracking player death, similar to what I outlined in [my answer here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/202849/74333). For the following, I assume that this objective is named `hasDied` and there are two teams, `red` and `blue`.

Instead of the `testfor` command in that answer, you can use

```
/testfor @a[team=red,score_hasDied=0]
```

Invert the redstone output, so that it turns on when nobody is left alive in team `red` and continue from there. Do the same thing for the blue team.