# Detect when there is only one player left on a team

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to detect when there is only one player left on a team.

I am making "Hunger Games" style PvP arena/event. When you die you go to the "Dead" team, and if you are still alive you stay on the "InGame" team.

I need to make it so if there is only one player left on the "InGame" team that it announces the winner and everybody returns to the lobby.

Comment: [This is pretty close to what you want](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/204061/how-can-i-check-if-an-entire-team-has-died), but the answer is for 1.8 and doesn't use the 1.9 command blocks.

Comment: Close but no, this tests if all the players in a team are dead, i need to test id only one is alive

Comment: @HungryBoy02 the difference in the command blocks between one player and no players left alive in a team is actually pretty small these days.  You change one value in one command block, and you're done.

Comment: @MBraedly I am kind of new to scoreboards, i just learned how they work yesterday, could you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more players on the "InGame" team, the stronger the redstone output, so this is what i did.
[image: My Solution]

Answer (score -1):

All you need is a hopper clock and some redstone mechanics.

Inside the command block you should put:

```
/testfor @p[team=alive,playercount=1]
```

This works on 1.8 or lower, but for less lag, use the 1.9 command blocks.

[image]