# How do I tp a Minecraft Player to a certain location when they die with command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making a Boss Arena with command blocks and no plugins, I got the bosses and spawn and tps to arenas done. But the problem is, that I don't know the command to teleport players when they die.

Comment: Could you just set the world spawn point instead?

Comment: You could track their time of being alive and teleport them back after they respawned.

Comment: If setting the world spawn isn't an option, you could put a teleport loop at the spawn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use /testfor to detect the death of a player?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202816/can-you-use-testfor-to-detect-the-death-of-a-player)

Answer (score 1):

If you want people to spawn somewhere else when they die, just set the world spawn with `/setworldspawn` when standing where you want them to spawn or set individual player spawns with `/setspawn {player}` when standing where you want them to spawn!

Answer (score 0):

(Note: Umm, uh, someone edit this please)
You simply use `/tp @p ~n ~n ~n`. The first ~ teleports the player a certain amount of blocks long, and in a plus shape with the third ~. the second ~ teleports the player up. If you want the player to be teleported downwards or the other direction, use negatives (-). n is the number of blocks they will be teleported. If you just want to teleport a player to a single location, press (Fn +)F3 where you want the player to teleport. Then, look at XYZ (start of second part). Remember the numbers there, or if needed, type the numbers in the chat. If I wanted a player to teleport to the coordinates 184, 68, 264 then I would type: `/tp @p 184 68 264` WITHOUT the ~'s. However, if I typed `/tp @p ~184 ~68 ~264` then I would then I would teleport the closest player to the blocks 184 right, 68 up and 264 forwards. Or 184 forwards, 68 up and 264 right. @p teleports the closest player, @a teleports all players and @r teleports a random player. If for some reason, as if you want to teleport the boss in use something like `/tp @e[type=wither]`. As for your question, set the spawn point at the very center of the world. Get the coordinates to the arena spawn point. Fill the spawn chunk with quartz. Place string everywhere on the quartz then 
tripwire on the... well, here's a example:
qqqqqqqqqqq
qqqqqqqqqqq
qqqqqqqqqqq
qqqqqqqqqqq
qqqqqqqqqqq

then

tttttttttttttttt
tssssssst
tssssssst
tttttttttttttttt

q = quartz. t = tripwire. s = string.

Then, place redstone like an outer ring. Place a command block that connects to all the redstone. Use the above commands to teleport the player into the arena.

tl;dr: so sad too bad

Answer (score -1):

Set their spawn were you want them or somewhere where you have command blocks set to tp them.

Answer (score -3):

You can't, I think they just have to come to you themselves.

Comment: Ummm actually you can...

Comment: Really? @Luiyay

Comment: ...What do you mean... Nevermind...