# How can I stop or reset redstone contraptions based on player deaths?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

[Can you use /testfor to detect the death of a player?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202816/can-you-use-testfor-to-detect-the-death-of-a-player)

I found this post^ and I understand it, but I have a follow-up question:

Is there anyway to have your world reset all your redstone when everyone dies?  My clock will continue, at the end everyone dies and the seeker loses. If everyone is found, is there anyway to stop the redstone from continuing when everyone is found?

Comment: Do you want to stop a specific clock? Then just remove any block from it.

Comment: I have a super long and complicated clock, so its not so simple, I mean is there any way, when I click a button, it sets off something that will stop every redstone signal in the world/reset all the redstone?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Add a dummy scoreboard.

/scoreboard objectives add find dummy

Summon an armor stand as a game marker.

/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"\"finder\""}

Then, at the start of the game, have this command run:

execute as @a[targetallthehiders] run scoreboard players add @e[type=armor_stand,name=finder] find 1

This will give the armor stand a score that is equal to the number of players.

Every time a hider dies, remove one point from the armor stand.  When everyone is dead the score will be 0, and you can target the armor stand like [type=armor_stand,name=finder,scores={find=0}].

Does this help?