# How do I make it so when one player dies everyone dies

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make something like the life link challenge for a realm but can't use a plugin on it so I've been trying to make it using command blocks.

it's in 1.14.4 so old commands won't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use /testfor to detect the death of a player?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202816/can-you-use-testfor-to-detect-the-death-of-a-player)

Comment: @pppery That is only a part of the problem, right? There is more to it than just detecting a death, which is addressed in the answer.

Comment: [Identical question in Bedrock Edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/368418/is-it-possible-to-make-everyone-die-once-one-player-dies-in-minecraft-bedrock)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, type in chat:

```
/scoreboard objectives add deaths deathCount
```

Then, set two command blocks, one set to 'repeat' and 'Always active' and another linked to the first set to 'chain', 'Always active' and 'Condicional' [as in this image](http://prntscr.com/p7zm1z).
 Then, you add the following commands respectively:

```
/execute as @a[scores={deaths=1..}] at @s run scoreboard players set @a deaths 0
/kill @a
```

The way it works is simple: If a players die, the scoreboard will register and add a point to whoever died. After that, the command block will execute as the player (note that the command could go 'execute if @a[scores={deaths=1..}]') and clear everyone (including his) score. The second command will only activate if the first one was sucessful and if it happends, the command will kill **every player in the server**.

To avoid such, you can do:

```
/tag [PlayerName] add LifeLink
```

And modify the first two commands as well as adding another one set to 'repeat' and 'Always active':

```
/execute as @a[scores={deaths=1..},tag=Lifelink] at @s run scoreboard players set @a deaths 0
/kill @a[tag=LifeLink]
/scoreboard players set @a[tag=!LifeLink] deaths 0
```

It will only kill and activate the commands if such player is set with the LifeLink tag.

---

Here are some Images to help build it.

Place the first block down:
[image]

Shift and then right click to place the second one. Make sure they are pointing in one direction (http://prntscr.com/p9kwvb).
[image]

Open the first command block. Paste the command bellow and set as 'Repeat' and 'Always Active':

```
/execute as @a[scores={deaths=1..}] at @s run scoreboard players set @a deaths 0
```

[image]

Open the second command block. Paste the command bellow and set it to 'Chain', **'Conditional'** (Super important, don't miss it) and 'Always Active'.

```
/kill @a
```

[image]

The final product.
[image]

Comment: Wait, which commands do you put in what command blocks? I never have used command blocks before so I'm very confused. Also, does this work for the Microsoft version?

Comment: This is specifically for the Java/microsoft version.You can get a command block by typing /give @s command_block and you can change their color/type by clicking in the impulse option. Place two commands blocks like in (http://prntscr.com/p7zm1z) and set them like mentioned in the answer above (always active, condicional...). Before putting the commands in the blocks, type in chat the first command (/scoreboard add...). After that, put in the commands 'execute as...' and 'kill @a'  respectivly. Done!

Comment: I'll update the answer tomorrow with screenshots to make it easier, so don't worry if the comment didn't quite help.

Comment: @Chloe Check the anwser, just edited it. Sorry for taking so long.

Comment: The first command for the scoreboard hasn’t been working for me. it keeps saying Syntax error. Is there anyway to still do this or around this?

Comment: @jenna Which version? Also, are you talking about [/scoreboard objectives add deaths deathCount] ? If you are using a command block to add it, make sure there is no Space (´ ´) in the end of the command line. Aside from that, there is no Syntax error, as I just tested it on both 1.14.4 and 1.15.2...