# Is it possible to make everyone die once one player dies in Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I recently watched a Slimecicle video, that took place in Minecraft Java, which kills everyone in-game when one person dies. I saw someone got an answer to pretty much the same question, but they had Java. All of my friends don't have Java like I do, and I really want to try it out with them. Is there a way I can do this without MC Java? Thanks!

Comment: "Slimecicle"? That looks like a typo of "Slicedlime", but he doesn't play MCBE.

Comment: [Slimecicle](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQmzgjEb7X6--w7CSE1erJg) is also a player it seems.

Comment: [Identical question in Java Edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/357749/how-do-i-make-it-so-when-one-player-dies-everyone-dies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is after all of your players join set the world spawn point far away in a bedrock box or something,  and then use a command block to detect when a player is in that box (they spawn there when they die) and if a player is in the box kill all players.
This is not the best way because every time you want to play again you have to tp everyone out,  and players setting there spawn points in beds is also a very big problem

Edit/better way of doing this:  have an invisible armor stand (or some other entity) in the proximity of a player at all times and use /testfor to detect when a player is within a amount of blocks if it is tp the armor stand behind the player, so as long as the player does not /tp or use enderpearls everything will work,  if the player dies, it is no longer near the armorstand, so kill all players then tp the armor stands back to their player.  this will take some  time as you will need to use tags or something but it works quite well