# Minecraft hardcore server: can I automatically delete and re-generate the world when any player dies?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've set up a small hardcore Minecraft server for me and some friends. There aren't many of us, and what we really want out of the hardcore mode is that as soon as anyone dies, the whole world gets deleted and the server restarts from scratch.

At the moment, the dead players go into spectator mode, and it's kinda boring. I'd rather everyone be able to play all the time, just that when someone dies it's an "awwwwwww" moment for everyone, if you get my meaning :)

Is it possible to do this? I've googled frantically but all I can find is people trying NOT to lose their hardcore worlds... which is the opposite of what I want >_>

Comment: Not at all versed in Minecraft but ... Wouldn't a mod that kill everybody when someone dies could an answer ?

Comment: Similar to Fana's answer, [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/357749/how-do-i-make-it-so-when-one-player-dies-everyone-dies) Arqade post details how to kill everyone upon someone's death with command blocks

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this will work -- when we all die, we all just become spectators and can only fly around. I still have to delete the world manually in order for us to be able to play again. But I didn't know about command blocks, this might be helpful, thank you!

Comment: As in, immediately with no warning? This will have to be done by a mod or by plugin, but I think I can set something up. Give me a few days.

Comment: Command blocks are awesome and powerful, but since they're bound to a pre-existing world, I don't think you can use them to generate a *new* one; this makes me think you'll need a mod of some sort to make this happen. It doesn't sound like it'd have to be too complicated though, it'd really only need two parts: 1. Detect when a player dies 2. On player death, restart the server with a new world in the server settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can go back to life in hardcore. Find a way to turn on cheats. If on singleplayer, open to LAN. If on multiplayer, find another way to do so. (I will edit when I find out how). Then, set your gamemode to survival. Using this, you can have infinite lives on hardcore.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can**, I made a script.
I hope this is still relevant.

https://github.com/Bloodimooni/Minecraft-Hardcore

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/323268)

Answer (score -1):

You can technically see when a player dies. When any player dies, you can quit and delete the world. Then, recreate the world using the same seed.