# Targeting specific members of a team who have died

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to set bedwars up on my server using command blocks, which I'm a little new to.
I want a command block that is Repeating, Always active to /execute when a member of Red team dies, for example. But how do I make it so that it would only target that player and not every member of Red team?
I thought I might be able to use @s, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use /testfor to detect the death of a player?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202816/can-you-use-testfor-to-detect-the-death-of-a-player)

Answer (score 0):

So:
add ur team-`/team add red`

add scoreboard-`/scoreboard objectives add deaths deathCount`

and put this in a repeating cb-`/execute at @a[team=red,scores={deaths=0..}] run say hi`

and put this in a chain cb-`/scoreboard players reset @a[team=red,scores={deaths=0..}] deaths`