# How do I track player death in a specific area?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a shrine, in which you sacrifice yourself (die) to trigger Night/Day change
For that I need to track player death in the area of that shrine, not anywhere else
So far I've tried to track it by health of a player in that area, but Minecraft doesn't register 0 health, so it doesn't trigger

Question stands: How do I register player death in a certain area?

Minecraft version: 1.17

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you use /testfor to detect the death of a player?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202816/can-you-use-testfor-to-detect-the-death-of-a-player)

Comment: I think this is a different case. Iirc, once a player died, they no longer have a "body" which means they don't have a coordinate associated to them, making it hard to know -where- the player died. I could be wrong tho... I guess it also depends on how the OP triggers the death.