# How to make a command that will triggers on death of a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to do a hide and seek game by commands.
When a player is dead, if they are in a certain team, then summon something like a flag. If on the opposite team then summon another flag.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. I tried to rephrase but it's actually hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you detect a player's death?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202816/how-do-you-detect-a-players-death)

Comment: @pppery that's a very old post, and the /testfor command doesn't work for newer versions. You have to use `/execute if`, instead.

Comment: Sigh. Question age is irrelevant when determining duplicates. I posted a comment on the answer explaining how to update it to 1.13 syntax way back in 2019.

Comment: @pppery instead of a comment, you should make a new answer and explicitly say "for version 1.13+" or something to that end.

Answer (score 0):

First, you would create a scoreboard death count to check for deaths:

```
/scoreboard objectives add death deathCount
```

Then, you would check for deaths via the:

```
/execute if entity @a[gamemode=survival,scores={death=1}]
```

And then in chain commands connected to it, you would do:

```
scoreboard objectives remove death


scoreboard objectives add death deathCount
```

I tested this, and it does work. However, it does produce a lot of output in chat. You can disable this via:

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```